# Change Interrupt Service Routine

Tags: 14.04

Where are interrupt service routines stored in ubuntu ? if i want to change them how to do that? please specify the language they are written in.

Answer (score 1):

ISR are managed by the Linux kernel and drivers.
If you want to change them, you will need to edit the kernel (or drivers) source code then compile and install it.

ISR are mostly written in C and assembly language.

You may already know this but this command gives you some information about the ISR :

```
 cat /proc/interrupts
```